# Ошибка: NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

Хотел запустить программу с графическим интерфейсом.

`if __name__ == "__main__":` (и то что внутри) написал вручную, потому что после конвертации (`.ui` в `.py`) этого кода не было.

После запуска программы выходит ошибка

```
NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined
```

Что не так?

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(326, 206)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(130, 110, 75, 23))
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(80, 30, 381, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(u"font-size: 20px;")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"TextLabel", None))
    # retranslateUi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    Form =  QtGui.QtWidgets()
    ui = Ui_widget()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Замените строку `Form =  QtGui.QtWidgets()` на `Form =  QWidget()`

Comment: **1)** чтобы импортировать из `QtGui`, его тоже нужно импортировать, т.е. `from PySide2 import QtGui`, либо сразу делать импорт класса из прямого модуля, т.е. `from PySide2.QtGui import ` **2)** У вас уже есть импорт `QCoreApplication`, поэтому достаточно `app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)` **3)** меня смущает, что вы используете виджеты (окна) при этом у вас приложение `QCoreApplication`, а не `QApplication` (из `QtWidgets`)

Comment: Вот так лучше не делать `from PySide2.QtWidgets import *` задавайте импорт буквально

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали, но
`Form =  QtWidgets() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` код: 
`import sys`
`from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets`
`from PySide2.QtWidgets import *`
`from PySide2.QtCore import *`
`from PySide2.QtGui import *`
`from PySide2.QtWidgets import *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я же вам написал `Form = QWidget()`, а не `Form = QtWidgets()`

В общем ваше приложение может выглядеть так, закомментируйте мои импорты и раскомментируйте свои. Я отметил строки, в которые внес изменения.

```
'''
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel
'''

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(326, 206)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(130, 110, 75, 23))
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(80, 30, 381, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(u"font-size: 20px;")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
        self.label.setText(QApplication.translate("Form", u"TextLabel", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys                                              # +++

#    app = QtGui.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)                 # ---
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)                            # +++

#    Form = QtGui.QtWidgets()                               # ---
    Form = QWidget()                                        # +++

#    ui = Ui_widget()                                       # ---
    ui = Ui_Form()                                          # +++

    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Но  учитывая, что вы вероятно захотите оживить свое приложение и добавить какую-то логику, я вам предложу попробовать вариант как правильно это сделать.

```
'''
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel
'''
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(326, 206)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(130, 110, 75, 23))
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(80, 30, 381, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(u"font-size: 20px;")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
        self.label.setText(QApplication.translate("Form", u"TextLabel", None))


class Window(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        # тут пишем логику приложения
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        print(f'Вы нажали кнопку `PushButton`')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys                                  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)    
    window = Window()                           
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```